# How can I paint over mold to prevent it from coming back again?

Tags: paint, mold

The source of the leak has been fixed, however the old mold keeps showing though the new paint.

Comment: see also http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36/how-can-i-paint-over-a-ceiling-after-theres-been-a-leak

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't try painting over mold.  Use bleach to get rid of it first.  Make sure the entire area is completely dry.  Then use a special anti mold paint.

Comment: This. If you paint it over your mold will never go away. This is your best bet. If you just cover it up you will get some serious problems later. Mold in homes can really mess up your health too.

Comment: what kind of bleach (chlorine) do you use ?

Comment: [This site](http://www.mold-control-on-a-budget.com/documents/43.html) recommends using a 10% Borax (to water) solution instead of bleach. They claim it works better and is less hazardous to you. According to that site, bleach releases carcinogens when it makes contact with mold.

Comment: Bleach is not the best way to kill mold. Yes it will kill it, but the mold spores will sense the bleach, and migrate. Professional mold products are available but you probably won't find them at Home Depot.

Comment: I used bleach and water and it does work

Comment: bleach (on its own) won't kill it - household bleach like you can buy from the grocery store is too watered-down

Answer (score 23):

Kilz is not anti-mold paint.

Once the source of the moisture has been corrected, go to your local Home Depot and buy Concrobium fungicide spray. It's all natural and an encapsulant. It comes in a spray bottle. Follow the directions. This will kill the mold as well as prevent new mold from growing.

Once that is done you can cover the area with Zinnser Bulls Eye 1-2-3 Waterbase Primer. The bulls eye *IS* mold and mildew resistant. If you have a lot of water stains you may want to go with something stronger like Zinnser Guardz, but Kilz will not help you out in the water stains or mold issue.

Answer (score 11):

A product called "Killz" is an anti mold paint. Might try spraying the area down with a bleach/water mixture (I believe the ratio of 1 part bleach to 10 parts water is sufficient). Spray it down and let it dry. The bleach should kill the mold off in a few days.

Comment: When using Kilz make sure you are in a well ventilated area, it is some nasty stuff.

Comment: @Tester101 definitely!! sorry for not including that, ventilation is a key thing. Most notably if you're in an enclosed space such as a bathroom. Kilz is a great (but fairly stinky) product. Grab yourself a few fans before starting.

Comment: @Tester101 : They actually make a latex Kilz now -- I haven't tried it, so I don't know how much of the smell is the anti-mold part, and how much is the solvent used, but I noticed it the last time I was shopping for paint.

Answer (score 5):

You need to:

1. If possible - remove the source of dampness (not always possible)
2. Dry the area
3. Paint on a damp-seal product (many available)
4. Once dry you can paint over the damp seal.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

It's best to go with a natural, organic and effective remedy. I've been in the business 12 years. First use a roller, dip it in vinegar, ( rice wine or apple cider) Then you have to use a special Lime Paint over a quartz-stone primer. this will eliminate all mold permanently. It raises the alkalinity levels in the air so mold can't grow on it.

Comment: Please add more detail to this answer.  Do you use the vinegar-soaked roller to apply the primer or the paint, or is it a separate step altogether?  What is the lime paint you're talking about and what's special about it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to kill the mould spores first.  First use a sugar soap to thoroughly clean the surface.  Then obtain a mould killing chemical (there are lots of them, go to your local hardware store and ask).

Finally, a good sand down and apply a stain blocking primer/undercoat such as those from zinsser or dulux.  Ideally something oil based.   Then a couple of top-coats of your normal paint and you should be sorted.  You can get paint additives or paints that come with anti-mould compounds in them these days.  I'd recommend that particularly if it's an area that gets damp often (like a bathroom or laundary).

Comment: Really have doubts about sugar being a useful component for cleaning

Comment: @ragerdl - although called sugarsoap, it's not actually sugar.  See here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_soap.  I've found it to be very effective at removing just about any dirt.

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using aluminum spray paint to cover old water stains on the ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

NEVER use Borax or Bleach!  It does not kill the mold spores!!  It only removes the mold stain!  Use white distilled vinegar and hydrogen peroxide.

Comment: Can you supply some references to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Earthpaint has a product called Lime Primer.  I just ordered one and will see how it works.  You can directly put it on mold and they guarantee that mold will not grow on the primer.