# What chemicals are available to remove and prevent mold appearing through brickwork?

Tags: mold

This [thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223/how-can-i-paint-over-mold-to-prevent-it-from-coming-back-again) recommended Conchrobium followed by a Zinnser sealant.

I can't locate Conchrobium in Australia. Are there alternate or even more generic solutions that will treat the mold and prevent it from reappearing?

Unfortunately the moisture can't be easily stopped as the brickwork is under ground level.

Answer (score 3):

Can you find [Sporicidin](http://www.sporicidin.com/) there?  I've used it successfully at home.